# List of liked items with acts_as_votable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have implemented the acts_as_votable gem to like pins.

I have the following code in my pins controller

```
 def like
 @pin.liked_by current_user
 redirect_to :back
 end

 def unlike
 @pin.unliked_by current_user
 redirect_to :back
 end

 def mijn_favoriete_recepten
 @pins = current_user.pins
 end
```

Edit: My 'mijn favoriete recepten' view file:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>  
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
<%= @pin.find_liked_items.each do |liked_item| %>
<div class="box panel panel-default">
    <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), liked_item %>
      <div class="panel-body">
      <strong><p><%= pin.description %></p></strong>
      <p><%= link_to 'Bekijk recept', pin_path(liked_item) %></p>
</div>
<% end %>

<% else %>
<%= render 'pages/login' %>
<% end %>
```

and the following pin model

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_votable
belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

I try to make a view to list the pins that a specific user has liked. I get stuck in finding the right syntax to put in my view (and controller) to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: According to the documentation (https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#the-voter), you should be able to call `@pin.find_liked_items`

Comment: I am sorry, I am relatively new in RoR, could you indicate which exact syntax I need to use in my view. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This should loop on every liked items: `<%= @pin.find_liked_items.each do |liked_item| %>`

Comment: Please could you help me, I am stuck. I don't know if I need to change the view or controller file to let this work! Please see my edit of the question!

Comment: I get this error message on my view page of liked items NoMethodError in Pins#mijn_favoriete_recepten  <% if user_signed_in? %>  
    <div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
    <%= @pin.find_liked_items.each do |liked_item| %>
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
            <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), liked_item %>
              <div class="panel-body">

Comment: Is it the `find_liked_items` method called on the `@pin` instance that is generating the NoMethodError ?

Comment: yes, the error is on <%= @pin.find_liked_items.each do |liked_item| %>

Comment: I have added the following to the pins controller: def my_favorites
    @pins = current_user.find_liked_items
  end